# JPA Bidirectionnal Uknown column

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have entities and they were unidirectional, so I decided to make them bi-directional, when they were unidirectional everything was good, but when I changed them to bi-directional I got some problems !!!!

I have a lots of entities but I will just refer, I have a problem in two entities one with `OneToMany` and the other with `ManyToOne`.

The first entity is called `Agent` (`OneToMany` with `Project`) :

```
@Entity
public class Agent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1047335572433032863L;
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Basic
    private String fistname;
    @Basic
    private String lastname;
    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agent")
    private List<Project> project;

    //Setters and getters ...
}
```

the second entity is called `Project` (`ManyToOne` with `Agent`) :

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6643569041998000573L;
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Basic
    private String crmCode;
    @Basic
    private String circuit;
    @Basic
    private String type;
    @Basic
    private String scope;
    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date beginDate;
    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date endDate;
    @ManyToOne
    private Agent agent;
    @ManyToOne
    private Service service;

    //Setters and getters
}
```

but when I launch some fetch queries I got this exception :

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException

root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException

root cause

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'AGENT_ID' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT ID, BEGINDATE, CIRCUIT, CRMCODE, ENDDATE, SCOPE, TYPE, AGENT_ID, SERVICE_ID FROM PROJECT WHERE (CRMCODE = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Project sql="SELECT ID, BEGINDATE, CIRCUIT, CRMCODE, ENDDATE, SCOPE, TYPE, AGENT_ID, SERVICE_ID FROM PROJECT WHERE (CRMCODE = ?)")

root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'AGENT_ID' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT ID, BEGINDATE, CIRCUIT, CRMCODE, ENDDATE, SCOPE, TYPE, AGENT_ID, SERVICE_ID FROM PROJECT WHERE (CRMCODE = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Project sql="SELECT ID, BEGINDATE, CIRCUIT, CRMCODE, ENDDATE, SCOPE, TYPE, AGENT_ID, SERVICE_ID FROM PROJECT WHERE (CRMCODE = ?)")

root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'AGENT_ID' in 'field list'
```

Here I can understand the problem, JPA is referencing to `AGENT_ID` column which doesn't exist in the database, the same with the field `service` in `Project`.

The problem is why this weird error?, shouldn't it reference to `Agent.ID` instead of `AGENT_ID` when it creates the request to the database, I tried to change the name of the id in the `Agent` entity to `AGENT_ID` using `@Column` but I got the same problem just with `AGENT_AGENT_ID` !!!!

Anyone knows how to solve this problem, I'm on glassfish, thanks all :)

Comment: According to stack trace,  `Project` table must `AGENT_ID` column.

Comment: If the `Project` database table does not contain a column with the Agent ID, then how do you associate a Project with an Agent? Forget the Java, you need to get your database right first. The Property table should have a foreign key to Agent, and that most likely should be called AGENT_ID.

Comment: Also, why are you using the `@Basic` annotation? Better to use the `@Column` annotation, which is more standard.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear i've already mentioned that, i've annotated the `id` of the `Agent` entity with `@Column(name = "AGENT_ID")` but i got the same problem just JPA report that AGENT_AGENT_ID doesn't exist, and for the `@Basic`, its generated automaticaly, i use IntelliJ IDEA :)

Comment: @CycDemo yes, I've understood that but as you see, i didn't changed the `Agent`'s `id`, i didn't understand this weird error !!!

Comment: No, you are mis-understanding. I am not talking about the `Agent` table. Your `Project` table must have an `agent_id` column which will be the foreign key relating to the `Agent` table. How else do you relate a `Project` record to an `Agent` record? This is the database **not** the java. Get the database right first before you write the java.

Comment: Show us the definitions of your database tables.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear i know foreign keys and i've used them before, but now i'm using JPA, so i specify my entities and JPA (EclipseLink cuz i'm on glassfish) transforms them to tables on the database, also entities' relationships get transformed to foreign keys, my problem is clear, i've created 2 entities but JPA is mis-interpreting my entities :(

Comment: But EclipseLink should be creating the foreign keys for the `@ManyToOne` associations. Judging by the error it clearly is not creating the `agent_id` column in `project` that is required as the foreign key. That sounds like a problem with EclipseLink, not your java. Note that in most production environments you never let the JPA provider (EclipseLink in this case) create tables and/or columns.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear these tables are generated by JPA, the first table agent(ID INT, FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255), LASTNAME VARCHAR(255), DEPARTEMENT_ID INT) with a foreign key FK_AGENT_DEPARTEMENT_ID DEPARTEMENT_ID, the second table project (ID INT, .... other fields, AGENT_ID INT, SERVICE_ID INT) with two foreign keys, FK_PROJECT_AGENT_ID AGENT_ID and FK_PROJECT_SERVICE_ID SERVICE ID :)

Comment: its okey, i think i found the solution, thank you, now everything is clear, and works fine, and the ID are generated auto, thanks also for the advice for not letting EclipseLink to generate the tables :)

Comment: OK, how about you post the answer so other people can benefit from it?

Comment: The problem isn't in the entities, the problem were in data insertion, in unidirectional when i have a relation like `OneToMany` i were inserting the datas like that `agent.setProject(Arrays.asList(projects));` but in the bidirectional i should inverse it, i should do `project.setAgent(agent)`, so when i was fetching the datas i got this problem, i don't know how this affects the datas in the database, but this is the solution, anyway thank you for your time :)

Comment: EclipseLink would absolutely create the foreign keys.  If it isn't, it is likely because you have an existing schema already created, and so the tables already exist before you added the Project.agent ManyToOne mapping.  In which case, you need to use drop and create for DDL generation.  If you had a uni-directional OneToMany, it would have used a join table by default, which you really can't use in a bidirectional 1:M M:1 type relation, which is why this isn't working for you with the current schema

Comment: @Chris thank you for your responding, but i'm on the developement environement so i have setup in the `persistance.xml` this `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` property to `drop-and-create`, anyway i've said where is the problem, but idk what is relation with foreign keys !!!!

Answer (score 2):

> i've annotated the id of the Agent entity with @Column(name = "AGENT_ID") but i got the same problem just JPA report that AGENT_AGENT_ID doesn't exist

What you did will change the ID column in the `Agent` table, but it is not going to affect the join column in `Project` table.

You should do something like:

```
class Project {
    //....

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="YOUR_AGENT_ID_COL_NAME");
    private Agent agent;
    //......
}
```